# What should I use to marinate chicken with a lime seasoning?

Tags: chicken, marinade

I'm trying to marinate chicken with lime for a party. I know I can't use metal as a marinating dish otherwise it corrodes. Is wooden okay to use? I need an answer hopefully within the hour because of the upcoming party tomorrow morning. I have already used up my plastic bowls for fruits. Are wooden bowls okay to use or should I use multiple Tupperware dishes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bets are glass and stainless steel.   There is no risk of corrosion with stainless steel, as opposed to aluminum or cast iron, which may react with acidic foods.

Zip-type bags are also excellent for marinating, and disposable.

You can use plastic like Tupperware, but there is some risk of staining.

I would not choose wood, as the marinade may permeate into the grain of the wood, leaving stains and a permanent aroma.

Comment: Glased ceramics would also be fine.